# How can I tell the reducer task id/number that my script is running under in Hadoop streaming?

Tags: environment-variables, hadoop-streaming, reducers

I would like the output of my streaming reducer task to be different for partition number 0 than for the other partitions. How can I tell from within my script what reducer task it is running as?

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out that there are environment variables `mapreduce_task_id` and `mapreduce_task_partition` that one can access from within the script. 
These will have different values for different reduce tasks for example, task 0 has:

`mapreduce_task_id=task_1410791469618_0007_r_000000`

whereas, task 1 has:

`mapreduce_task_id=task_1410791469618_0007_r_000001`

Similarly, task 0 has:

`mapreduce_task_partition=0`

and

`mapreduce_task_partition=1`.

In Python, these can be accessed as follows:

```
import os 
my_task_id = os.environ.get('mapreduce_task_partition')
```

Comment: Yes, that's the way to go about it. There are all sorts of juicy snippets of information in the environmental variables and you can even pass in your own.
Keep in mind that the format of these is different between the new YARN hadoop distros and the old one.

Comment: Thank, Nonnib. Would you have a pointer to where all these are documented?

Comment: I didn't find any documentation myself, just printed out os.environ in 1.0 and 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

As Nonnib said, if you run your job on MR2/Yarn: 
`mapreduce_task_id` is not set. Use `mapred_task_id` instead.

The only reference I have is a [Vowpal Wabbit script](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/blob/master/cluster/runvw-yarn.sh) (also, I use it in my Yarn jobs and it is works well with version up to Hadoop 2.0.0-cdh4.6.0)